# Problems with a query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

Table name 1: chair
Fields table 1: id (INT) - model (VARCHAR) // Primary Index: id

Table name 2: color
Fields table 2: id (INT) - color (VARCHAR) // Primary Index: id

Table name 3: chair2color
Fields table 3: id_chair(INT) - id_color(INT)  // Primary Index: id_chair-id_color

Every chair can have different colors: red or green or (red and green).

Some values for table 1 (chair):

```
1 - modelA
2 - modelB
3 - modelC
```

Some values for table 2 (color):

```
1 - red
2 - green
```

Some values for table 3 (chair2color):

```
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 1
3 - 2
```

I want to get all chairs models order by color in this way:

```
SELECT chair.id AS ID_CHAIR
FROM chair 
LEFT JOIN chair2color ON chair.id=chair2color.id_chair 
ORDER BY FIELD (chair2color.id_color,'1','2')
```

The result I get is:

```
ID_CHAIR
1
2
3
```

My problem is that chairs which are only red appear in first place (it's ok). Then, I have chairs which are only green and then chairs are green and red.

I would like green and red chairs appear before green chairs since they are red too.

My desired result (and I think correct one) would be:

```
ID_CHAIR
1
3
2
```

How could I do it? :(

Comment: It would appear that SQL can't work I think you're missing the color table and an `on` clause.  with regards to your question: first table design seems a bit off you should have a chair color table between chair and color.  that way the 'color' doesn't get duplicated.   your current design leads me to believe ID_Chair is repeated in the color table for different colors and not that you have a single color called red and green. not sure how to address without better layout of question.  Sample data with expected results would help clarify this.

Comment: My first inclination is to use a case statement... `case when color='red' then 1 when color='green' then 2 when else 0 end` and order by it.  but if you simply added a column defining the order to color table it would work too... but again I don't understand long term goal...

Comment: totally agree with @xQbert. There should e a separate table holding mappings between chair and color.
Can you share the table structures?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the entry. It was confusing. Can you help me now? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have the distinct chair IDs anyway, so you can build a string of colors with `group_concat()` and order by this.

```
SELECT id_chair, group_concat(id_color order by id_color) colors
FROM chair 
LEFT JOIN chair2color ON chair.id=chair2color.id_chair 
GROUP BY id_chair
ORDER BY colors
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7a87/4/0)

If you want to have a specific order, you can achieve this with the `FIELD()` function. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

```
SELECT id_chair, group_concat(id_color order by id_color) AS colors
FROM chair 
LEFT JOIN chair2color ON chair.id=chair2color.id_chair 
GROUP BY id_chair
ORDER BY FIELD(group_concat(id_color order by id_color), 4,3,5,1,2)
```

The `group_concat(id_color order by id_color)` in the `order by` will be implicitly cast to an integer. Therefore it works (see it live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc9ba/4/0)).

If you want to reverse the order, meaning sort descending, you have to reverse the order in the `field()` function, too.

```
SELECT id_chair, group_concat(id_color order by id_color) AS colors
FROM chair 
LEFT JOIN chair2color ON chair.id=chair2color.id_chair 
GROUP BY id_chair
ORDER BY FIELD(group_concat(id_color order by id_color), 2,1,5,3,4) DESC
```

Comment: You have opened my point of view. THANKS! Nevertheless, it doesn't solve my problem completely. If you access to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc9ba/1, how can I order results for blue ones (id_color 3), then black ones (id_color 4), red ones (id_color 1) and, finally, green ones (id_color 2). The order for id_chair would have to be '4', '3', '5', '1' and '2'. Would it be possible?

Comment: Great! Now your solution is complete for me. My error was to assign a name/alias to group_concat and ORDER BY FIELD with this name. Without this name/alias (like you have displayed) it works. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!